# How to replace one or more consecutive symbols with one symbol in shell

Tags: linux, shell, file, file-handling

I have a file containing consecutive symbols (as pipe "|") like

```
ANKRD54,LIAR,allergy,|||
ANKRD54,LIAR,asthma,||20447076||
ANKRD54,LIAR,autism,||||
ANKRD54,LIAR,cancer,|||
ANKRD54,LIAR,chronic_obstructive_pulmonary_disease,|||
ANKRD54,LIAR,dental_caries,||||
```

Now using shell or a sed command in shell is it possible to replace multiple pipe with one pipe like

```
    ANKRD54,LIAR,allergy,|
    ANKRD54,LIAR,asthma,|20447076|
    ANKRD54,LIAR,autism,|
    ANKRD54,LIAR,cancer,|
    ANKRD54,LIAR,chronic_obstructive_pulmonary_disease,|
    ANKRD54,LIAR,dental_caries,|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the easiest way is use built-in commands: `cat your_file | tr -s '|'`

Comment: `tr -s '|' < file`, would be better, than displaying a [_Useless Use of Cat_](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html)

Answer (score 2):

Pass your text to sed (e.g. via a pipe)

```
cat your_file | sed "s/|\+/|/g"
```

Comment: Just to note that here `+` is escaped. Normally we don't escape `+` symbol in regex pattern.Without escaping, it won't work here because it is just a normal character for sed regex pattern. If you don't want escaping, you can try this also `sed 's/||*/|/g'`

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a simple `awk` `gsub` as:-

```
awk -F"," -v OFS="," '{gsub(/[|]+/,"|",$4)}1' file
```

See it in action:-

```
$ cat file
ANKRD54,LIAR,allergy,|||
ANKRD54,LIAR,asthma,||20447076||
ANKRD54,LIAR,autism,||||
ANKRD54,LIAR,cancer,|||
ANKRD54,LIAR,chronic_obstructive_pulmonary_disease,|||
ANKRD54,LIAR,dental_caries,||||

$ awk -F"," -v OFS="," '{gsub(/[|]+/,"|",$4)}1' file
NKRD54,LIAR,allergy,|
ANKRD54,LIAR,asthma,|20447076|
ANKRD54,LIAR,autism,|
ANKRD54,LIAR,cancer,|
ANKRD54,LIAR,chronic_obstructive_pulmonary_disease,|
ANKRD54,LIAR,dental_caries,|
```